# Weak * topology on Lp

Tags: general-topology, analysis

For $p > 1,$ is the weak * topology on $L_p (X)$ with some measurable space $X$ agree with the original norm topology?

If it isn't, is it metrizable?

If it is, does that mean that for general measure space $X,$ $L_p (X)$ has a countable dimension?

Answer (score 1):

For any infinite dimensional space $E$, the weak-$\ast$ topology on $E^{\ast}$ is not metrizable as the following argument proves: If it were induced by a metric $d$, then consider the open sets
$$
B_d(0,1/n)
$$
Since this is an open neighbourhood of $0$, it must contain a set of the form
$$
U_n := \{\varphi \in E^{\ast} : |\varphi(x_i)| < \epsilon \quad\forall 1\leq i\leq n\}
$$
for some finite set $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n\} \subset E$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Now since $E$ is infinite dimensional, $\exists \psi_n \in E^{\ast}$ non-zero such that
$$
\psi_n(x_i) = 0 \quad\forall 1\leq i\leq n
$$
In particular,
$$
\varphi_n := n\frac{\psi_n}{\|\psi_n\|} \in B_d(0,1/n)
$$
Hence, $\varphi_n \to 0$ in the weak-$\ast$ topology, but $\|\varphi_n\| = n \to \infty$ which contradicts the uniform boundedness principle.

---

Also, an infinite dimensional Banach space cannot have a countable Hamel basis (this is a straightforward argument using the Baire Category theorem)